# No process is on the other end of the pipe error when trying to connect to SQL Server database through VB.NET application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssms, clickonce

I have a SQL Server database which I connect to from my VB.net client application.

Everything works fine in most of the systems. But in a few new VMs the client application is unable to connect to SQL Server and it throws the error mentioned below. The strange thing is that I can use the same credentials (SQL Server authentication) to  connect through SQL Server Management Studio in the same system.

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

The sample connection string used is as below

```
Data Source=[server name];Initial Catalog=[db name];Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[username];Password=[pass]
```

I have checked similar answers and have already tried the following

- Made sure SQL Server is accepting remote connections
- Made sure TCP and Named Pipes are enabled in SQL Server
- Started SQL Server Browser service
- Tried specifying IP address instead of server name

By reading related articles, some of them point eventually to SSH, TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 issues. I also suspect firewall, but because I do not have admin rights to the system, I am not able to check the inbound and outbound rules.

Any suggestions would help.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? I'd suggest removing this, or at least setting it to false. Persist Security Info=True;

Comment: I have tried that too, with no luck. SQL Server 2014 is the version used.

Comment: Do you see any related messages in the SQL Server error log?

Comment: @DanGuzman Nothing related to this in the SQL Server error log it seems.

Comment: If using SQL Server authentication, try adding "Integrated Security = False" to your connection string.  Also, if you can, test it without using Named Pipes, just using TCP to connect.